# Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, cross-fade

I need to merge multiple video files (with included audio) into a single video. I've noticed xfade has been recently released and used it but I am running into an audio sync issue.

All videos are in the same format / resolution / fame and bitrate / etc both for video and audio.

Here is what I am using to merge 5 videos of various durations with 0.5 crossfade transitions:

```
ffmpeg \
-i v0.mp4 \
-i v1.mp4 \
-i v2.mp4 \
-i v3.mp4 \
-i v4.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=3.5[V01]; \
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=32.75[V02]; \
 [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=67.75[V03]; \
 [V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=98.75[video]; \
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01]; \
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02]; \
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03]; \
 [A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" \
-vsync 0 -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" out.mp4
```

The code above generates a video with audio. The first and second segment is aligned with audio but starting with the second transition the sound is misaligned.

Comment: @llogan it's massive https://pastebin.com/SGnqB7Lt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your offsets are incorrect. Try:

```
ffmpeg -i v0.mp4 -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -i v3.mp4 -i v4.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=3[vfade1]; \
 [vfade1][2:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=10[vfade2]; \
 [vfade2][3:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=21[vfade3]; \
 [vfade3][4:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=25,format=yuv420p; \
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade1]; \
 [afade1][2:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade2]; \
 [afade2][3:a]acrossfade=d=1[afade3]; \
 [afade3][4:a]acrossfade=d=1" \
-movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

How to get xfade `offset` values:

| input | input duration | + | previous xfade `offset` | - | xfade `duration` | `offset` = |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `v0.mp4` | 4 | + | 0 | - | 1 | 3 |
| `v1.mp4` | 8 | + | 3 | - | 1 | 10 |
| `v2.mp4` | 12 | + | 10 | - | 1 | 21 |
| `v3.mp4` | 5 | + | 21 | - | 1 | 25 |

<sub>These are simplified example durations that are different than the durations shown in the original question.</sub>

- See [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) and [acrossfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade) filter documentation for more info.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) for a gallery of transition effects and more examples.
- You can [get input durations with `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604/).

Comment: You are right, figured it out today too with some tests. I also found a way to get a better sync by trimming/padding audio prior to these actions. This is an issue since most of the files' audio and video durations are not equal. So here is what I am doing now (that's another set of videos + your other suggestions): https://pastebin.com/QGcVZsk3

Comment: Using the approach I got "More than 1000 frames duplicated ", and in the middle of the output there is out-of-sync between video and audio. Any ideas?

Comment: @Trương Quốc Khánh could you add xfade to ffmpegargs?

Comment: @Richard Did you ever solve the out-of-sync issue? I am facing the same issue right now.

Comment: @user1734282 can you try this?
ffmpeg -i video0.mp4 -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=41.567[v01];
[v01][2:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=55.534,format=yuv420p[video];
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01];
[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 
-map [video] -map [audio] 
-movflags +faststart output.mp4

Answer (score 5):

Automating the process will help deal with errors in calculating the offsets. I created a Python script that makes the calculation and builds a graph for any size list of input videos:

https://gist.github.com/royshil/369e175960718b5a03e40f279b131788

It will check the lengths of the video files (with `ffprobe`) to figure out the right offsets.

The crux of the matter is to build the filter graph and calculating the offsets:

```
# Prepare the filter graph
video_fades = ""
audio_fades = ""
last_fade_output = "0:v"
last_audio_output = "0:a"
video_length = 0
for i in range(len(segments) - 1):
    # Video graph: chain the xfade operator together
    video_length += file_lengths[i]
    next_fade_output = "v%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
    video_fades += "[%s][%d:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=%.3f[%s]; " % \
        (last_fade_output, i + 1, video_length - 1, next_fade_output)
    last_fade_output = next_fade_output

    # Audio graph:
    next_audio_output = "a%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
    audio_fades += "[%s][%d:a]acrossfade=d=1[%s]%s " % \
        (last_audio_output, i + 1, next_audio_output, ";" if (i+1) < len(segments)-1 else "")
    last_audio_output = next_audio_output
```

It may produce a filter graph such as

```
[0:v][1:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=42.511[v01]; 
[v01][2:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=908.517[v12]; 
[v12][3:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=1098.523[v23]; 
[v23][4:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=1234.523[v34]; 
[v34][5:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=2375.523[v45]; 
[v45][6:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=2472.526[v56]; 
[v56][7:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=2659.693[v67]; 
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1[a01]; 
[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=1[a12]; 
[a12][3:a]acrossfade=d=1[a23]; 
[a23][4:a]acrossfade=d=1[a34]; 
[a34][5:a]acrossfade=d=1[a45]; 
[a45][6:a]acrossfade=d=1[a56]; 
[a56][7:a]acrossfade=d=1[a67]
```

Comment: Please provide details of segments.txt

Comment: I modified the code and hardcoded 3 file names in segments. I works very well for audio, however, the last video is not added. Rather the last frame of the middle video is shown until the music of last video finished

Answer (score 3):

The Python script above did help me a lot but it has a mistake in offset calculation. The video stream should be 'video_length - fade_duration*(i+1)'.

As the code below:

```
def gen_filter(segments):
    video_fades = ""
    audio_fades = ""
    settb = ""
    last_fade_output = "0:v"
    last_audio_output = "0:a"
    fade_duration = 0.3

    video_length = 0
    file_lengths = [0]*len(segments)
    
    for i in range(len(segments)):
        settb += "[%d]settb=AVTB[%d:v];" % (i,i)

    for i in range(len(segments)-1):

        file_lengths[i] = float(ffmpeg.probe(segments[i])['format']['duration'])

        video_length += file_lengths[i]
        next_fade_output = "v%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
        video_fades += "[%s][%d:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=%f:offset=%f%s%s" % \
            (last_fade_output, i + 1, fade_duration, video_length - fade_duration*(i+1), '['+next_fade_output+'];' if (i) < len(segments)-2 else "","" if (i) < len(segments)-2 else ",format=yuv420p[video];")
        last_fade_output = next_fade_output

        next_audio_output = "a%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
        audio_fades += "[%s][%d:a]acrossfade=d=%f%s" % \
            (last_audio_output, i + 1, fade_duration*2, '['+next_audio_output+'];' if (i) < len(segments)-2 else "[audio]")
        last_audio_output = next_audio_output
        
    return settb + video_fades + audio_fades
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [similar but simpler script](https://github.com/yekm/etc/blob/home/bin/ffmpeg_xfade.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: ls -1 something*.mp4 | ffmpeg_xfade.sh output.mp4

fdur=0.5
ftrans=pixelize
f0n=0
f1n=1
alld=0

while read f; do
    allvf="$allvf$vf"
    allaf="$allaf$af"
    inputs="$inputs -i $f "
    d=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")
    alld=$(bc -l <<< "$alld + $d")
    offset=$(bc -l <<< "$alld - $fdur * $f1n")
    vf="[vfade$f0n][$f1n:v]xfade=transition=$ftrans:duration=$fdur:offset=$offset[vfade$f1n];"
    af="[afade$f0n][$f1n:a]acrossfade=d=$fdur[afade$f1n];"
    (( f0n++ ))
    (( f1n++ ))
done

f0n=$(( f0n - 1 ))
allvf="[0:v]copy[vfade0];$allvf[vfade$f0n]format=yuv420p"
allaf="[0:a]acopy[afade0];$allaf[afade$f0n]acopy"

#set -vx
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner $inputs \
    -filter_complex "$allvf;$allaf" \
    -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p7 -profile:v high -rc-lookahead 8 -spatial_aq 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:a libopus \
    "$1"
```

---

The resulting ffmpeg command for this resembles:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner  -i f1.mp4  -i f2.mp4 -i f3.mp4  -i f4.mp4         
-filter_complex "[0:v]copy[vfade0];[vfade0][1:v]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.5:offset=-.5[vfade1];
[vfade1][2:v]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.5:offset=10.0[vfade2];
[vfade2][3:v]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.5:offset=20.0[vfade3];
[vfade3]format=yuv420p;
[0:a]acopy[afade0];[afade0][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5[afade1];
[afade1][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5[afade2];
[afade2][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5[afade3];
[afade3]acopy"       -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p7 -profile:v high -rc-lookahead 8 -spatial_aq 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libopus "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining more about what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

The script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483586/10735100) has a mistake, which was pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546687/10735100) but presented as a new def.

If anyone just wants the corrected original script for the previous answer, replace the chunk after `# Prepare the filter graph` with:

```
# Prepare the filter graph
video_fades = ""
audio_fades = ""
last_fade_output = "0:v"
last_audio_output = "0:a"
video_length = 0
fade_duration = 0.5

for i in range(len(segments) - 1):
    # Video graph: chain the xfade operator together
    video_length += file_lengths[i]
    next_fade_output = "v%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
    video_fades += "[%s][%d:v]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=%.3f[%s]; " % \
        (last_fade_output, i + 1, video_length - fade_duration*(i+1), next_fade_output)
    last_fade_output = next_fade_output

    # Audio graph:
    next_audio_output = "a%d%d" % (i, i + 1)
    audio_fades += "[%s][%d:a]acrossfade=d=1[%s]%s " % \
        (last_audio_output, i + 1, next_audio_output, ";" if (i+1) < len(segments)-1 else "")
    last_audio_output = next_audio_output

# Assemble the FFMPEG command arguments
ffmpeg_args = ['ffmpeg',
               *itertools.chain(*files_input),
               '-filter_complex', video_fades + audio_fades,
               '-map', '[%s]' % last_fade_output,
               '-map', '[%s]' % last_audio_output,
               '-y',
               args.output_filename]

# Run FFMPEG
subprocess.run(ffmpeg_args)
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the final underlying ffmpeg command for this.