# ffmpeg xfade for (complex filter or select filter)

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I need to trim and merge the video into one. I need to implement a cross fade or any smooth transitioning between each cut. Can I implement and how to implement the xfade or other ffmpeg smooth transition?

I did read this from multiple source.
[Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553906/merging-multiple-video-files-with-ffmpeg-and-xfade-filter#)
But I still fail to generate a working code

Below is the example command and video section that I need to trim

```
ffmpeg -y -i example.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=start=0.1:end=0.7333333333333333,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=1.2333333333333334:end=4.8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=4.966666666666667:end=10.466666666666667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=10.6:end=13.066666666666666,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=13.733333333333333:end=17.333333333333332,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=39.9:end=40.56666666666667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:a]atrim=start=0.1:end=0.7333333333333333,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];
[0:a]atrim=start=1.2333333333333334:end=4.8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
[0:a]atrim=start=4.966666666666667:end=10.466666666666667,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
[0:a]atrim=start=10.6:end=13.066666666666666,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];
[0:a]atrim=start=13.733333333333333:end=17.333333333333332,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4];
[0:a]atrim=start=39.9:end=40.56666666666667,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a5]; 
[v0] [a0] [v1] [a1] [v2] [a2] [v3] [a3] [v4] [a4] [v5] [a5] [a0] [a1] [a2] [a3] [a4] [a5]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1 [out]" 
-map "[out]" example_COMPLEX.mp4
```

I generate this script file with xfade effect

```
ffmpeg -y -i example.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=start=0.1:end=0.7333333333333333,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[0:v]trim=start=1.2333333333333334:end=4.8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
[0:v]trim=start=4.966666666666667:end=10.466666666666667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
[0:v]trim=start=10.6:end=13.066666666666666,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];
[0:v]trim=start=13.733333333333333:end=17.333333333333332,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];
[0:v]trim=start=39.9:end=40.56666666666667,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5];
[0:a]atrim=start=0.1:end=0.7333333333333333,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];
[0:a]atrim=start=1.2333333333333334:end=4.8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
[0:a]atrim=start=4.966666666666667:end=10.466666666666667,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
[0:a]atrim=start=10.6:end=13.066666666666666,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];
[0:a]atrim=start=13.733333333333333:end=17.333333333333332,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4];
[0:a]atrim=start=39.9:end=40.56666666666667,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a5];
[v0][v1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.2[x1];
[x1][v2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.2[x2];
[x2][v3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=10.166666666666666[x3];
[x3][v4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=13.266666666666666[x4];
[x4][v5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=13.433333333333337,format=yuv420p[video]; 
[a0] [a1] [a2] [a3] [a4] [a5]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1 [out]" 
-map "[video]" -map "[out]" example_COMPLEX.mp4
```

But there is an error message

```
[Parsed_asetpts_13 @ 0000014db55ea140] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_asetpts_13' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_concat_30' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000014db5414580] Cannot create the link asetpts:0 -> concat:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: no video in concat: `concat=n=6:v=0:a=1`

Comment: yes it will work if i add `concat=n=6:v=0:a=1` but only last trim has cross fade other just seems like freeze frame , may I know how to add the xfade filter or any other between each cut? I tried this and read through the documentation but it seems didn't work.

Comment: wrong offsets for xfade filters. must be incremental values: for first video: video duration - xfade duration = offset (0.733-0.1) - 0.5 = 0.133, 2nd video: 0.133 + (4.8-1.233) - 0.5 = 3.2, 3rd video: 3.2 + (10.466-4.966) - 0.5 = 8.2 etc...

Comment: Hi is it previous off set + current duration (- previous end time - offset duration) = current offset?

Comment: Yes, from second video till end. Prev offset + (end time - start time) - xfade duration = current offset