# FFMPEG scale and xfade not working together

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -loop 1 -t 5 -i p1.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i p2.jpg  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4.5[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=9[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -y out.mp4
```

I am trying using scale the picture and adding xfade into it. Error:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_xfade_5
```

It works fine when I remove the xfade filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 5 -i p1.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i p2.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[img0];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[img1];[img0][img1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=4.5,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

- [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) requires 2 inputs, but you're only providing 1 input.
- You only need 1 xfade.
- I removed the concat filter because xfade is basically concatenating the two images.

Comment: Thank you @llogan it was very helpful , can you help me building a complex script where there is 100+ images , can you please join on v4webtech@gmail.com

Comment: or can you tell me , what will be syntax when 10 images there.

Comment: @VWebTechWebBuilder See [Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570355)

Comment: yes i already following it, but i guess i have having trouble with syntax, can you help me out on my project ? can you share your email please.

Comment: @VWebTechWebBuilder You can just ask a new question on SO or [su].