# ffmpeg video fade effect unsuccessful - no transition or the second video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have 2 `T`-seconds-long videos that are made from `PNG` images using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i workspace/1.png -vcodec libx264 -t T ./1.mp4
ffmpeg -i workspace/2.png -vcodec libx264 -t T ./2.mp4
```

Using those videos, I'm trying to create a transition between those 2 videos that lasts for `T` seconds, where we start with the first video and fade into the second one. Here's a simple ASCII visualization of the transition I have in mind:

```
Alpha \ Time    0.........T
1.mp4         100.........0
2.mp4           0.......100
```

So, both the videos, as well as the fade effect should start immediately, and end with the video itself. (i.e., offset is `0` and duration is `T`)

But when I try to produce such a video, the resulting `MP4` just consists of the video of `1.mp4`, with no fade effect whatsoever. Here's the command I used for producing the transition video:

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -y -filter_complex "xfade=transition=fade:offset=0:duration=T" -t T ./1-2.mp4`

I thought the offset and duration parameters in that `filter_complex` option were enough to get the transition going.

I've looked at similar StackOverflow questions, but in all of those the fade effect was *between* the videos that run sequentially, not in parallel. Is that what's happening here? How do I make both videos run in parallel from the start, while the fade is being applied to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You did not loop the images so your videos are only 1 frame long.
2. xfade offset is the timestamp when you want the transition to occur.

Example. Each image is 5 seconds long. A 1-second crossfade from `1.png` to `2.png` will occur 4 seconds from the beginning of `1.png`. `output.mp4` will be 9 seconds long.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png -filter_complex "xfade=transition=fade:offset=4:duration=1,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade)
- [Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570355/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked just the way I needed it to.